# is there anyone configure redis server for magento in windows platform?

Tags: windows, magento, redis

I hear that redis server is used for handling session storage in multiple servers, but i can't install the Redis server in proper way? please let me know how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is not supported on windows. An unofficial Win64 release can be downloaded from `https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis`. There is no Win32 support either. For Win64, clone the repo. Extract the zip file available in `bin/releases`. Add the extracted file to path and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but, i got a link https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads and it is installed successfully to my win7 32-bit OS.is this ok for magento? tell me some more to escape from this headache?

Comment: Magento does not support Windows (http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements). So your magento must be running in Linux. I don't know why you didn't use Linux itself.

Comment: thank u mohit,now i am using linux to install redis server.you know,i am only use this server for my magento session management. please give brief details?

Comment: Please read details here `http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee`. For better help, create another question with giving details of what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: yes, it is installed to magento using linux system. now i pointed my session to <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save> <redis_session>tcp://HOST:PORT?auth=PASSWORD&weight=2&timeout=2.5</redis_session> am i right? how can i check my session is stored in redis server?